# scp not working from remote to local not working

Tags: scp

On my mac, logged in via ssh to a remote host, I am experiencing difficulty transferring files to my laptop from the remote computer in the window where I am ssh'd into the remote computer. Is this supposed to be possible to do? I can't possibly think of why not. In this situation, I can go remote to another remote no problem.

on my local mac machine, if I run:

```
hostname
```

it returns my hostname - "`hostname`" let's say.

Then in the window where I am ssh'd into the remote computer, in a directory with file.txt, I try:

```
scp file.txt hostname@my_public_IP_address:path_to_destination
```

This does not even return anything at all. The command line doesn't come back either. Even when I use the -v verbose flag.

for path_to_destination, I have tried a few things:

```
~/Users/ ....
Users/...
/Users/...
~/Users/my_name/...
Users/my_name/....
/Users/my_name/
```

where in each case above the "/..." was tried either as "/", "/.../", or "/..."
with "..." just continuing the file path specification further. To me, any of these really should work.

If I do "`cd ~`" on my mac, and the "`pwd`", I get

```
/Users/my_name
```

Could someone kindly tell me either what I am doing wrong here or notify me that what I am trying to do is for some reason forbidden. I just find it strange that it just "hangs up" like this. I have looked around for a few days to try and figure this out with no luck. Thanks...

Comment: looks like you have NAT (Network Adress Translation) between you (hostname) and remote host. Have you map port 22 of your public IP to your local IP ?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with checking if you are able to connect to the port 22 of that host:
`telnet my_public_IP_address 22` if you will get anything (you should get OpenSSH server reply), that means you can debug that on scp/ssh server level.
If not - your problem is network related (which it's probably is).